# JSON Write files problem how to remove quotes

Tags: c#, json

**C#**

```cs
JsonUtility.ToJson(new Vector2((int)(province.center.x), (int)(province.center.y));
```

In **Json file** I get:

```
"center":"{"x":277399.0,"y":1511840.0}"
```

But I need to get this:

```
"center":{"x":277399,"y":1511840}
```

Comment: Vector2 holds float values, that's why .0 is appended. What's the scenario, that you cannot use a float number instead of an integer in json?

Comment: Can you add the library that you use? Json.NET? System.Text.Json?

You will need to write an object instead of a string in that library

Comment: You're missing the code that writes "center" in the question. The code you posted here is not the problem.